# Fetching report taking lot of time laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have project which contains questions and answer about their vehicle buying experience and generate complaints  after purchasing vehicle from the showroom,So they call customer and ask set of question regards to vehicle buying experience from showroom, This is outline of the project it's a old project with laravel 5.3 or 5.6 something,Now the problem is

When they taking 1 month report that contains details of cutomer details and vehicle details along with question and their answer to the questions,but if i take 1 month report it taking long time i mean
long time,i tried to clear cache and stuff,still problem occurs
Can any one help me on this,the data contains about 2000+ data

```
   public function excelquerep24(Request $request)
    {

        //getting all questions
        $questions = Question::where([['question_schedul', 2], ['status', 0]])->orderBy('order_no', 'asc')->get();

        //get answered customers;
        $answeredcalls =  Registration::
        join('ssi_tracks', 'ssi_tracks.ssi_track_id','=','registrations.registration_id')
        ->select('registrations.customerid', 'registrations.customername', 'registrations.phone', 'registrations.chassis', 'registrations.model', 'registrations.invoicedate', 'registrations.delivery', 'registrations.dealership', 'registrations.zone', 'registrations.branchcode', 'registrations.dh','registrations.zsm', 'registrations.branch', 'registrations.dse',  'ssi_tracks.ssi_track_id')
        ->where('ssi_tracks.track_first_status', '>','0')
        ->whereDate('registrations.delivery', '>=', $request->input('datefrom'))
        ->whereDate('registrations.delivery', '<=', $request->input('dateto'))
        ->distinct('registrations.customerid')
        ->get();
     
            $compsArray = [];


            // Define the Excel spreadsheet headers
        $compsArray[] = ['sl_no', 'Customer ID', 'Customer Name', 'Mobile', 'Chassis No', 'Vehicle Model', 'Invoice Date', 'Delivery Date', 'Dealership','Zone','Branch Code', 'DH','ZSM/SM',  'Branch', 'DSE',   'Status','PSF Date'];
        // return $compsArray;
         foreach ($questions as $question) {
            array_push($compsArray[0], $question->question);
            }
        // Convert each member of the returned collection into an array,
        // and append it to the payments array.

        $array = [];
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($answeredcalls as $call) {
            $newDateFormat3 = date('d-m-Y', strtotime((string)$call->delivery));
            $newDateFormat4 = date('d-m-Y', strtotime((string)$call->invoicedate));
            $call->delivery = $newDateFormat3;
            $call->invoicedate=$newDateFormat4;
            $psf24LastCallDate='';
            if ($call->zsm == '') {
                $sm = Registration::select('sm')->where('customerid', $call->customerid)->first();
                $call->zsm = $sm->sm;
            }
            $ssi = Ssi_track::where('ssi_track_id', $call->ssi_track_id)->first();
            if ($ssi->track_first_status == 1)
                $status = 'Partilly Called';
            if ($ssi->track_first_status == 2)
            {
               $lastcall= Call_track::where([['ssi_track_id', $call->ssi_track_id], ['call_schedule', 1]])->orderBy('call_track_id', 'desc')->first();
               if($lastcall)
               {
                
               
                if ($lastcall->call_responce == 1)
                   $status = 'Call Attended';
               if ($lastcall->call_responce == 2)
                   $status = 'Switched Off';
               if ($lastcall->call_responce == 3)
                   $status = 'Not Responding' ;
               if ($lastcall->call_responce == 4)
                   $status = 'Network Busy';
               if ($lastcall->call_responce == 5)
                   $status = 'Out of Coverage';
                 }  }      
            if ($ssi->track_first_status == 3)
                $status = 'Black listed call';
            if ($ssi->track_first_status == 4)
                $status = 'Call Completed';
            if ($ssi->track_first_status ==5 )
                $status = 'Call Closed';
            $tempArray = json_decode($call, true);
            array_unshift($tempArray, $i);
            $answeredArray = $tempArray;
            array_push($answeredArray,$status);
           $lastcall= Call_track::where([['ssi_track_id', $call->ssi_track_id], ['call_schedule', 1]])->orderBy('call_track_id', 'desc')->first();
           if($lastcall)
           $psf24LastCallDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime((string)$lastcall->created_at));
                array_push($answeredArray,$psf24LastCallDate );
            
        
            foreach ($questions as $question) {
                $answer = Customer_answer:: join('questions', 'customer_answers.question_id', '=', 'questions.question_id')
                ->select('customer_answers.answer')->where([['customer_answers.ssi_track_id',$call->ssi_track_id ], ['questions.question_schedul', 2],['questions.status', 0],['customer_answers.question_id',$question->question_id]])
                ->orderBy('questions.order_no', 'asc')
                ->first();
                if($answer)
                    array_push($answeredArray, $answer->answer);
                else
                    array_push($answeredArray, " ");
            }
            
            unset($answeredArray['ssi_track_id']);

            $compsArray[] = $answeredArray;

            $i++;
        }

        // Generate and return the spreadsheet
        Excel::create('questionwise report 24 hours', function ($excel) use ($compsArray) {

            // Set the spreadsheet title, creator, and description
            $excel->setTitle('Questionwise');
            $excel->setCreator('Laravel')->setCompany('test, LLC');
            $excel->setDescription('payments file');

            // Build the spreadsheet, passing in the payments array
            $excel->sheet('sheet1', function ($sheet) use ($compsArray) {
                $sheet->fromArray($compsArray, null, 'A1', false, false)
                    ->getStyle('A1')
                    ->getAlignment()
                    ->setWrapText(true);
            });

        })->download('xlsx');
    }
```

Comment: Does $answeredcalls count 2000 data objects or you have 2000 rows in database?

Comment: The registration table contains 17633 data,along with 40 rows but i am not taking all data as you can see i am only getting specific data from registration table,also ssi_tracks table contains same 17633  data but 10 row,but if i take one month data it close to 1000 data minimum @ZoranStankovic

Comment: This is decent amount of data and you first need to check do you have indexing set up properly which will increase your query speed. Another thing, even more important is to try reduce number of queries. You are looping trough data and making query each time and this is very time consuming. You should consider writing a query which will extract you all required data instead of looping and pushing it to array. Also you should avoid using ORM (Eloquent) for this as ORMs are not particularly good when it comes to performances with big data sets.

Comment: can you help me with that,how to index data kind of stuff@ZoranStankovic

Comment: You need to create a migration(s) and to define columns to be indexed. I am suggesting you to define index for all columns you are using for searching, ordering and for relations, for instance: questions.order_no, customer_answers.question_id, questions.question_id. Except those you should add all columns according to my upper instructions. Then run a migration and wait some time for SQL server to build indexes and then measure execution time again.  I think it is crucial to write proper SQL query which will extract all data at once if you want to get best performances.

Comment: hmm,it's been while i used laravel,i have switched to app development so i have to refresh my knowledge,thanks for the reply@ZoranStankovic

Comment: This will help you to start: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#creating-indexes

Comment: thanks manh i will look into it @ZoranStankovic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @Zoran Stankovic idea,Creating Indexes did the trick incresed speed like lot so i had to index data in models,refer [creating-indexes](http://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#creating-indexes)

**Import**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
```

Sample of code what i did on model

**For Registration Model**

```
public function regindex()
    {
        Schema::table('registrations', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->index('registration_id');
        });
    }
```

**For Customer answer**

```
 public function customerindex()
    {
     Schema::table('customer_answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->index(['ssi_track_id','question_id']);
  });
 }
```

**For ssi_track model**

```
public function ssiindex()
    {
      Schema::table('ssi_tracks', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->index(['ssi_track_id','registration_id']);
      });
    }
```